# Bastion opens on wrong monitor, how can I solve this?

Tags: bastion

When playing Bastion, the game opens full-screen on a monitor which isn't my primary monitor, unlike any other game. What should I do? I've found a work-around (which I have posted below), but I hope there's a better solution to the problem.

Also notice that although it opens in another monitor, it does use the resolution of the primary monitor.

System is Windows 7 64-bit. I'm launching the game through Steam. This happens both with the full version and the demo version.

---

Checking the Steam forums, [it looks like I'm not the only one with this problem.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2061287) The makers have responded [in this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2061171):

> **Q: I have a multi-monitor, Eyefinity, or multi-graphics card setup, and the game is crashing or experiencing issues. What should I do?**
>
> A: Please try disabling this type of setup and see if it resolves the issue. We are investigating specific cases for possible updates.

Comment: I assume that, in between launches of Bastion on the wrong monitor, you can launch another Steam game and it launches on the proper monitor?

Comment: @Shaun correct, just checked.

Comment: Same problem here. Also, dragging to the other monitor crashes the game (probably b/c they are different resolutions.. my 2nd monitor is smaller and just for open windows and other info panes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this issue too, but for me it's also picking up the resolution of my main monitor and using that, but displaying on the second monitor! I have a 27" 2560x1440 and a 24" 1360x768 monitor. The combination was driving me nuts as I can't even use the menu to do the workaround posted by Oak.

My solution after reading the forum post linked in the question was to add `-windowed -noborder` to the startup options in Steam, then it runs in fullscreen windowed mode from startup and loads in the correct place on the correct monitor at the correct resolution. It also seems to be the only way to get this particular mode active, which is fine for me as it's my preferred way of playing games.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention in the question but in my case as well it used the resolution from my primary monitor. In any case I'm accepting your answer since using `-windowed -noborder` does indeed lead to the desired results, thank you.

Comment: God bless -windowed -noborder.  Really.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found a work-around:

1. In the main menu of Bastion, go to Help & Options -> Display.
2. Uncheck "Fullscreen".
3. Drag the window to the correct monitor. The window can be dragged by taking the mouse cursor to the very top of the current monitor (where there is a thin white line), then dragging.
4. Click the "Fullscreen" option again.

From this point on, the game can be played full-screen on the correct monitor; unfortunately it resets to the incorrect monitor when quitting and running the game again, so this work-around has to be applied every time the game is launched.

Comment: Do you have Windows 7?  Perhaps you could try the window moving shortcut?  `Shift + WinKey + ArrowKey`  It moves windows to the screen that's in the direction you press.  I think it works for fullscreen applications too.

Comment: @Jeff nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution.

In your steam library (not big picture), right click on Bastion and go to properties. Locate the "Set Launch Options" button.

Click on in and you will see a field open up, type "-windowed" into this field and click accept, or confirm or whatever it says.

The game will now open on a window on the correct monitor. You can full screen it now without the game crashing.

Cheers.

Comment: This is just repeating the top answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change your other screen (the one you want to play on)  to your primary monitor in either your video cards program or in windows 7's display settings as see if that works.

Comment: The monitor on which I want to play is already my primary monitor. All other games I have ever tried already correctly launch on that monitor.

Comment: @Oak on which monitor is the symbolic link to bastion? The same as those games that take the correct monitor?

Comment: @Tobias I launched the game through Steam. The Steam window was on the primary monitor.

Comment: @Oak what happens if you start it while the steam window is on the secondary monitor? maybe the game tries to be "smart" by not blocking the steam window...

Comment: @Tobias doesn't help...